# How to compute the following complicated summation in R?

Tags: r

```
 a1=c(1,2,3, 4)
 a2=c(4,5,6, 7)
 a3=c(7,8,9,10)
 x <- cbind(a1, a2, a3)
  y <- c(1,5,7,9)
   z<-c(2,3,5)
```

I want to compute the following summation:

Comment: @ekoam Why added `t()`? Your result is the same as mine.

Comment: You can also use `n[j] <- t(x[,j]) %*% x[,-j] %*% z[-j]`, but I don't see a problem with the code you posted. It returns the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do:

```r
diag(crossprod(x, drop(x %*% z) - x * rep(z, each = NROW(x))))
#R> [1]  630 1080  756
```

or a `sapply`/`vapply` version of the loop ekoam shows in a comment:

```r
vapply(seq_along(z), function(j) drop(x[, j] %*% (x[, -j] %*% z[-j])), 
       numeric(1))
#R> [1]  630 1080  756
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me see this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020183/how-to-compute-this-summation-in-r ? Thanks.