# How to compute this summation in R?

Tags: r

If we have a dataset where $x_{ij}$ of size 4 by 3 matrix, i=1,2,3,4 and j=1,2,3. y_i is a vector and z_{ij} is also a 4 by 3 matrix.

```
  a1=c(1,0,1, 2)
  a2=c(2,2,1, 2)
  a3=c(1,3,2,3)
  a4=c(-1,0,-1,-1)
  x <- cbind(a1, a2, a3)
  y <- c(1,2,3,2)
  z<-cbind(a2, a3,a4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do:

```r
z1 <- z[1, ]
vapply(
  seq_along(z1), function(j) 
    drop((y - x[, -j] %*% z1[-j])) %*% x[, j], 
  numeric(1))
#R> [1]  10  15 -15
```

and a for loop version is:

```r
out <- numeric(3)
for(j in 1:3)
  for(i in 1:4){
    f1 <- y[i]
    for(k in setdiff(1:3, j))
      f1 <- f1 - x[i, k] * z[1, k]
    out[j] <- out[j] + f1 * x[i, j]
  }
out
#R> [1]  10  15 -15
```

Comment: I edited the x, z, and y values for simplicity in my question, and then I calculated the results by hand, and your code results are not the same. For j=1, the summation is 10 but your code is -4.

Comment: Also, if I want to compute the `z[n, ]` for `n=1,2,3,4` not `z[1, ]`. Can I just add a for loop `for( n in 1:4)` in your second code?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: I am a liitle bit confused about your second code. If we fix `j=1` first and then fix `i=1`, your `f1=y_1-x_11` and `f2=x_12*z_12+x_13*z_13` so the out is `(y_1-x_11)(x_12*z_12+x_13*z_13)` . But the sum should be `(y_1-(x_12*z_12+x_13*z_13))*x_11`/

Comment: Hi, I added a question to apply you code. But there seems a inf error when I add a for loop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047272/why-my-values-of-beta-is-increasing-to-infinity-for-my-for-loop. Thank you very much.